# How to design multiple stepper motor circuit

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, stepper-motor

I will be designing a circuit for 8 stepper motors. These stepper motors require 12V and atleast 3A. At most only 2 stepper motors will move at the same time.

Will a 12V 10A bus connected in a series supply be safe to control this?

Update: With TB6600 arranged in a series from the supply does not cause any problem with the operation of the stepper motor.

Comment: Only two will move at a time, but are the other 6 holding position while the two move? Even then 30A > 24A.

Comment: Why3A? What is the DCR? Obviously 24A exceeds spec

Comment: 3A at 12V seem like the DCR would be 4ohm. Is it necessary to hit the motors with full current each step? A PWM type drive would save power and have the bonus of microstepping support.

Comment: Always design by worst case specs!

Comment: _"...require 12V and **atleast** 3A"_ - does this mean they could draw _more_ than 3A at 12V?

Answer (score 0):

A question: got a spec for the motors you intend to use? That will settle the max coil current, more or less, as it will have a DC resistance spec.

Now that all said, know that doing a *good* stepper drive means managing the current through the coils (usually with PWM), and doing some tuning based on the motor electromechanical characteristics. If you do this well, your motors will move more smoothly and quietly, require less peak current, and will have better positional accuracy. Bonus: you can consider doing microstepping.

Here's a TI article on stepper motor 'tuning': https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2018/08/23/getting-smart-about-stepper-tuning